# jQuery not loading in Google Chrome content_script extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I can't manage to load jQuery in a Google Chrome userscript.

This is how my manifest.json looks:

```
{
    //...
    "content_scripts" : [{
        "js" : ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js", "code.js"],
        //...
    }],
    //...
}
```

But in `code.js`, `$` is `undefined`.

`code.js` otherwise works, and actually I have a bookmarklet working (that uses the site's version of jQuery).

I've tried minified and unminified versions of jQuery, hosted or local.

I've also tried embedding a minified jQuery at the top of my `code.js`, but if I do that the code does not even run, actually the whole file does not run (even an alert before the chunk of minified jQuery).

If you want to look at it, [here it is](http://sta.sh/02b754zyqrru).

Comment: I definitely would use a local file, but if you've tried that and it works then I'm at a loss.  This is a copy from a manifest file I have in a working extension...

 "content_scripts": [{
  "js": ["jquery-1.7.min.js"],
 }]

Comment: @Archer It did work, but only after uninstalling and reinstalling the (developer mode) extension. It's very weird, but at least I know I'll do that if I ever face the same issue :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the manifest.json provided in your zip, Chrome sends me two errors when unpacking.

> 1. Invalid value for 'content_script[0].matches[0]': Missing scheme seperator.
> 2. Could not load javascript 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js' for content script.

The first one says your `matches` statement isn't correctly formatted. After your `*` you should add `://` like so:

```
"matches" : ["*://my.deviantart.com/messages/*"]
```

The second one is about you trying to load the jquery from an external recource. If you change the path to your local file it should work.

```
"js" : ["jquery.js", "code.js"],
```

When I `console.log($)` in your `code.js` file after these adjustments jquery seems to work just fine.

EDIT:
Note that you need to add to your html (in `<head>` section) the following:

```
<script src='./jquery.js'></script>
```

Comment: I'll try it again with a local resource, altough the `code.js` script *does* run in the intended URL.

Comment: Ok, now it does work (after uninstalling and reinstalling the extension). Weird thing to fix it, but I'm glad it's over. Now I have other bizarre issues, but that's for another question I guess. As you said, those two things were wrong, and the script does load jQuery.

Comment: Hey Camilo, Can you please share your solution because I'm also facing the same issue for more than 3 weeks but I can't load script from a remote server.